# Oracle Update and Return a Value

Tags: oracle, syntax, sql-update

I am having a **`Update Statement`** on a large volume table.
It updates only one row at a time.

```
Update MyTable
Set Col1 = Value
where primary key filters
```

With this update statement gets executed I also want a value in return to avoid a **`Select Query`** on a same table to save resources.
What will be my syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the RETURNING keyword.

```
Update MyTable
Set Col1 = Value
where primary key filters
returning column1,column2...
into variable1,variable2...
```